# Can't deep link with Chrome on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, url-routing, deep-linking

I'm currently trying to build out a custom deep linking scheme for an iOS app that I'm working on. The format of the URL looks like this

```
[scheme]://[host]/[path]
```

I have registered The URL scheme within my app and everything works perfectly fine in Safari. However when using Chrome, I can't get the deep link to work at all. It always just begins a google search on the phone and never opens the app.  I know that I have to use an intent flag on Chrome, but everything I try seems to fail. Can you deep link to a custom scheme on Chrome on iOS? And if so how do you format the URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alriiight, let's address these issues in order, because there are several:

1. Custom URI schemes work just fine in Chrome and use the same format as everywhere else (`scheme://path/to/content`). But you have to put them behind a user action (i.e., a link or a redirect). You can't type them directly into the address box (this is the case on both iOS and Android, by the way).
2. Chrome Intents are for Chrome **on Android only**. They are not implemented in the iOS version of Chrome, which instead responds to Universal Links and URI schemes.
3. **Just because you can use custom URIs in both Safari and Chrome for deep linking doesn't mean you should.** In fact, it hasn't been a good idea for over a year now, because there is no way to avoid nasty error messages and lack of app-not-installed fallback behavior.

For a much more in-depth description of what should be done instead, you can read [this blog post](https://hackernoon.com/the-death-of-deep-linking-6cc65eb33e28#.1wfvot718). High-level summary is you will need to support both custom URI schemes *and* Universal Links, and you'll need a bunch of logic to intelligently switch between the two depending on the situation. This is a lot of work, and most major apps now use a service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Alex! I really appreciate it.